# Proxy Connection Error when trying to install packages with pip in anaconda environment

Tags: tensorflow, proxy, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to install a package (tensorflow) utilizing pip in an anaconda environment `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` on Windows Server 2016, resulting in the following error:

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/tensorflow/

I'm in a corporate network and the proxy for anaconda is set.

I've already tried the following things which don't help, the same error is still popping up:

- disabling firewall
- installing another package with pip (matplotlib)
- adding the flag `--proxy=http://myproxy.bla:8080` to the pip command
- adding the flag `trusted-host=pypi.python.org` to the pip command
- re-installing anaconda
- downloading the whl-file of tensorflow and `pip install` that. However, during that process, pip throws the error again when downloading any other package (e.g. astor)
- installation of other pip and python versions in other anaconda environments

Any help or hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem through the command `pip install --upgrade tensorflow--proxy="myproxy.blabla:8080` after searching in Windows for "Services", scrolling to "Cntlm Authentication Proxy" and hitting "Start the Service".

Note that executung "Start cntlm authentication proxy"-script didn't work.